# how to create function search in Node JS using Mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i'm trying to make search input using nodeJS but data Empty when i am trying to search by periode. this is my index.js

```
app.post('/search', function(req,res){

  connection.query('SELECT t.periode, COALESCE(r.r_kwh_penjualan, 0 ) as r_kwh_penjualan, COALESCE(r.r_total_pelanggan, 0 ) as r_total_pelanggan, COALESCE(r.r_total_pendapatan, 0 ) as r_total_pendapatan, t.t_total_pelanggan, t.t_kwh_penjualan, t.prediksi_pendapatan FROM realisasi AS r RIGHT JOIN  target_kinerja as t ON t.periode = r.periode WHERE r.periode LIKE "%'+req.query.key+'%" ORDER BY t.periode DESC',
  function(err,rows, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;
      var data=[];
      for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
      {
        data.push(rows[i].periode);
      }
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

this is my html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/search">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
         <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="search by periode">
      </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
```

this is search.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'countries',
        remote: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/search?key=%QUERY',
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

when i am tring to debug my query.

```
req.query.key
```

req.query.key result is "UNDEFINED" and data empty []

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: First run your query in Mysql and check whether data is listing or not and then check  the query parameters are correct or not.

Comment: use Sequelize.that will give you some tool for that.